# We need to capture the program close and allow the user to avoid the close

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clr

I know this is done a lot. In a C++ VS CLR program, if the user tries to exit while something is happening, where do you put the warning so that if they answer "no" the program can continue? An example would be very helpful as this type of code is not our part of our normal development expertise.

Just putting code in the overall destructor does not appear to allow the program to continue.

Comment: [WM_CLOSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-close)

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Nice. Now how does (or can) one intercept and process `WM_CLOSE` in a CLR program? (e.g. managed C++ code) ? That seems to be the crux of the OPs question.

Comment: In a Windows Forms application, handle the [`Form.Closing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.closing) event and set the `Cancel` member of the provided [`CancelEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs) object to true.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I will see if I can translate this into C++ from C#, not always a  clean process. It would be nice if Microsoft still provided c++ examples but they seem to be long gone.